# Creating a script that checks to see if each word in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am pretty new to Bash and scripting in general and could use some help. Each word in the first file is separated by `\n` while the second file could contain anything. If the string in the first file is not found in the second file, I want to output it. Pretty much "check if these words are in these words and tell me the ones that are not"

File1.txt contains something like:

```
dog
cat
fish
rat
```

file2.txt contains something like:

```
dog
bear
catfish
```

magic ->rat

I know I want to use `grep` (or do I?) and the command would be (to my best understanding):

```
$foo.sh file1.txt file2.txt
```

Now for the script...

I have no idea...

```
grep -iv $1 $2
```

Comment: Why the Python tag?  Are you interested in those answers too?

Comment: sorry it was just a recommended tag

Comment: Is this possible/easier with python? I'm also new to python and using spyder with gitbash.

Comment: Probably, but I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do.  For each word in `file1.txt`, you want to see if it is also a word in `file2.txt`, or will `base` count if `baseball` is in `file2.txt`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. This is straight forward and not optimized but it does the trick (I think)

```
while read line ; do
    fgrep -q "$line" file2.txt || echo "$line"
done < file1.txt
```

---

There is a funny version below, with 4 parrallel fgrep and the use of an additional result.txt file.

```
> result.txt
nb_parrallel=4
while read line ; do
     while [ $(jobs | wc -l) -gt "$nb_parralel" ]; do sleep 1; done
     fgrep -q "$line" file2.txt || echo "$line" >> result.txt & 
done < file1.txt
wait
cat result.txt
```

You can increase the value 4, in order to use more parrallel fgrep, depending on the number of cpus and cores and the IOPS available.

Comment: both had been tested ok

Comment: Just to clarify, you're piping file1.txt to read each line, and for each line to fgrep each line in file2.txt and to print the lines that grep fails?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what it does

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]; next} {for (i in a) if (index(i, $0)) next} 1' file2 file1

rat
```

Comment: The `break` doesn't actually do anything, does it? You have 1 too many `}`s too so maybe they're both leftover from a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

With the `-f` flag you can tell `grep` to use a file.

```
grep -vf file2.txt file1.txt
```

To get a good match on complete lines, use

```
grep -vFxf file2.txt file1.txt
```

As @anubhava commented, this will not match substrings. To fix that, we will use the result of `grep -Fof file1.txt file2.txt` (all the relevant keywords).

Combining these will give

```
grep -vFxf <(grep -Fof file1.txt file2.txt) file1.txt
```

Comment: That will give wrong results since `catfish` won't match `cat` or `fish`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
comm -2 -3 file1.txt file2.txt
```

and also:

```
diff -u file1.txt file2.txt
```

I know you were looking for a script but I don't think there is any reason to do so and if you still want to have a script you can jsut run the commands from a script.

Comment: this will check for exact match though.

Answer (score 0):

similar `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {for(k in a) if(k~$0) next}1' file2 file1
rat
```

Comment: Nitpick: If `file1` has a line `d.g`  then this will incorrectly omit `dog` in output :)